# Python Kivy - Save canvas to a file

Tags: python, kivy

Here I have a simple kivy paint app taken from their docs https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/firstwidget.html and modified by me, attempting to add a save button which would save the canvas to the file `image.jpg`

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(255, 255, 255)
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x/ 2, touch.y/ 2), size=(1, 1))
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Clear',font_size=30,pos=(100,0))
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear)
        savebtn = Button(text='Save',font_size=30)
        savebtn.bind(on_release=self.save)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(savebtn)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return parent

    def save(self, obj):
        self.painter.export_as_image().save('image.jpg')

    def clear(self, obj):
        self.painter.canvas.clear()

MyPaintApp().run()
```

the save button does appear next to the clear button, and it does create the file `image.jpg` when I click it. But for some reason the file is always a blank black image with nothing on it, instead of the canvas with whatever I have drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `MyPainter` widget has its default size of `(100,100)`, and its default position of `(0,0)`, so it is actually behind your `Save` `Button`. Any drawing that you do in the middle of the `App` display is not in the `MyPainter` widget, so saving to an image will be blank.

The fix is to set `pos` and `size` of the `MyPainter` widget so that it can be drawn on. You probably also want to use `collide_point()` in your `on_touch_down()` and `on_touch_move()` methods to ensure that you can only draw in the `MyPainter` widget.

Comment: That was it, thank you! Do you have any idea how to set the size of the "brush" as while?

Comment: The `Line` object has a `width` attribute. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Line).